# On the relation between SO(3) and SU(2) groups

Tags: group-theory, rotations, orthogonal-matrices, unitary-matrices

Giving the group $SO(3)$ to represent rotations in 3D space, what is exactly $SU(2)$ then? the formal relation between $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ was given by: $SO(3)\cong SU(2)/\Bbb{Z}_2$ and informally it was mentioned that $SU(2)$ is a 'double cover' of $SO(3)$, I didn't understand both since I don't understand what $\cong$ in group theory means and what $SU(2)$ actually represents, I know it is a silly question I tried the web and couldn't fully understand, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\cong$ denotes [group isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism), and $SU(n)$ is the [special unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group) of degree $n$ ($n \times n$ unitary matrices with determinant $1$).

Comment: @angryavian Okay now I understand a bit, but I still don't get how $SU(2)$ relates to $SO(3)$ in sense that $SO(3)$ represents rotations in 3D space, what does $SU(2)$ represent? like if I am going to setup some matrix $M$ where $M\in SU(2)$ what is gonna be like?

Comment: Do you know what a unitary matrix is? What an orthogonal matrix is?

Comment: @angryavian yes, okay the situation here, I am studying physics, we used $SO(3)$ to do rotations, but we never did any applications with $SU(2)$ so I don't understand what where it fits.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Connection_between_SO(3)_and_SU(2)) has a description of the relationship you are curious about.